# Grab Text/Header from word document along with table data VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Currently, I am currently using the below script to capture tables from the word document and store them in Excel workbook as separate sheets. THe pages have 2-3 lines of text/headers and 2-3 lines of text after the table.

Along with the tables i would like to extract the text which is before and after the tables onto the same worksheet as table.

For example on page 1 i have - "textbeforetable_page1" , table_page1 , "textaftertable_page1"
and this should be extracted on the same worksheet as table_page1.

Code currently using -

```
Sub ImportWordTables()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRng As Word.Range, wdTbl As Word.Table
Dim xlWkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, p As Long
With wdApp
  .Visible = False
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.path & "\documentname.docx", AddToRecentFiles:=False)
  With wdDoc
    p = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
    i = CLng(InputBox("The document has " & p & " pages." & vbCr & _
        "Page to start at?"))
    If i < 1 Then GoTo ErrExit
    If i > p Then GoTo ErrExit
    j = CLng(InputBox("The document has " & p & " pages." & vbCr & _
        "Page to end at?"))
    If j > p Then j = p
    Set wdRng = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i).GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
    wdRng.End = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=j).GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page").End
    For Each wdTbl In wdRng.Tables
      wdTbl.Range.Copy
      Set xlWkSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
      xlWkSht.PasteSpecial "HTML"
      xlWkSht.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next
ErrExit:
    .Close False
  End With
  .Quit
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: By "text before" do you mean the paragraph before the table?

Comment: Yes. Paragraph or header before the table, only which is on the same page. so if table is on page 9 , i would want only page 9 text to be extracted along with table.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change:

```
      wdTbl.Range.Copy
```

to:

```
     With wdTbl.Range
      .MoveStart wdParagraph, -1
      .MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
      .Copy
     End With
```

Comment: i updated above to this , however its still extracting the just the tables . I need both the tables and text.

Comment: ```For Each wdTbl In wdRng.Tables```
   ```With wdTbl.Range```
     ```MoveStart wdParagraph, -1```
     ```MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1```
    ```.Copy```
    ```End With```
      ```Set xlWkSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add```
   ```xlWkSht.PasteSpecial "HTML"```
   ```xlWkSht.Range("A1:M1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit```
  ```  Next```

Comment: apologies , i was having a hard time entering code into comment.

Comment: Evidently, then, your text is not in paragraphs *immediately* before & after the table. You might need to change the '-1' and '1' to '-2' and '2', for example. You can't post formatted code in comments here.

Comment: Try modifying your question with the code rather than putting it into a comment.